# Can not connect domain with Laravel Forge

Tags: laravel, laravel-forge

I created a domain with GoDaddy, and connected it with Digital Ocean.
I think the domain connected exactly to Digital Ocean.

In Laravel Forge, I made an app with that domain, and deployed my GitHub project.
The problem is, if I visit my website, it is showing just the "Welcome to nginx!" page. How do I make it display the code I wrote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you deployed your application in default directory, then setting up the domain DNS records should point to you server ip address and your website should be accessible from both server ip address and the domain.

But if you deployed your application in a different directory rather than the "default" you need to change your DNS records for pointing correctly to application directory.

You may want to take a look at Laracasts Deployment tuts for Laravel Forge

a basic tutorial by Jeffery Way: https://laracasts.com/series/build-and-configure-a-staging-server/episodes/1

a newer version for working with Laravel Forge by Marcel Pociot: https://laracasts.com/series/learn-laravel-forge/episodes/4

Comment: I found issue. After setting dns, I had to change nginx configuration.

Comment: Ok, great then.